# Finitely Generated Modules over Quotient of a DVR.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $(R,t)$ be a DVR with uniformizing parameter $t$ and let $M$ be a finitely generated module over $R/(t^n)$. Then $M\cong \bigoplus_r R/(t^r)$.

Question: How many summands of type $R/(t^r)$, where $1\leq r\leq n$ appear in the above decomposition? Can we say anything more than the fact that there are finitely many? Any formula to compute the above, however unsatisfactory is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The edited version of your first paragraph is false.  (I give up for now.  At least one of us is very confused about something.  Someone else will have to stop by and help.)

Comment: I'm about to leave this site for a while, so I'll say one more thing.  There was one comment, now deleted, where you said what you actually wanted.  I was frustrated that you didn't understand why the question itself doesn't make logical sense -- again, you can't ask for a formula that makes use of unspecified additional information.  But if you say that you want a formula for the $n_i$'s in my comment below **in terms of** the thing you mentioned and since deleted: yes, there's a formula for that.

Comment: @Pete Clark, wouldnt it be more helpful and useful to people if you just would write that in the answer instead of the many comments. Either way i will try to find it myself and then delete this question.

Comment: @Pete Clark, I could not delete this question, but i certainly would have if i could.

Answer (score 2):

Finitely many.  That's all that can be said without further information on $M$.

(To say a little more: a finitely generated module over $R/(t^n)$ is just a finitely generated module over $R$ which is killed by $t^n$.  Thus the theory of invariant factors / elementary divisors over the PID $R$ applies.  What it says is that $M$ is isomorphic to a finite direct sum of cyclic $t^n$-torsion modules.  Each such guy is of the form $R/(t^r)$ for some $1 \leq r \leq n$.  For each given $r$ you can have any finite number of summands of this form.)

Comment: @messi: But you haven't told us anything about the dimensions of those vector spaces!  It doesn't make sense to ask for a formula for something without specifying what additional information the formula is permitted to take into account.  Please think a bit and write down the question that you really want to ask.  (By way of comparison, imagine you asked how many sheep a barn must contain.  I say there's not enough information, and you say that you vaguely remember a formula in terms of the number of legs...)

Comment: @messi: What I'm saying is that for any natural numbers $n_1,\ldots,n_t$, $\bigoplus_{i=1}^t \bigoplus_{j=1}^{n_i} R/(t^r)$ is a finitely generated $R/(t^n)$-module.  In other words, I told you precisely what is possible based on the information you've given.  You're alluding to a "formula" for the $n_i$'s, but clearly any such formula must use *extra information* beyond what you've given.  If you mean to ask "How do I compute the $n_i$'s in terms of $X$?", please do so and be sure to say what $X$ is.